# how to set the resultset to string pointer?

Tags: c++, mysql, arrays, string

I am using result set in mysql for retriving the result.

I want to get the result in string array like

> MYSQL_RES *res=mysql_store_result(mysql);
>
> MYSQL_ROW row;
>
> while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
>
> {
>
> ```
>   string *result=row;   //there is only one row in resultset
> ```
>
> }
>
> string *result=row;

It give me error

> error: cannot convert char** to std::string* in initialization

Than how to use the string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this:

```
MYSQL_RES *res=mysql_store_result(mysql);

MYSQL_ROW row;

std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >  result;

int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
    std::vector<std::string> a_row;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++){
        a_row.push_back(row[i]);
    }

    result.push_back(a_row);

}
```